# Loading Partial html file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a tabset Monday - Sunday and i want to load a different partial file when any of the tabs are clicked. How do i do this in AngularJS

```
<div ng-controller='CleaningServicesCtrl' ng-init= 'getlocations()'> 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
        <button type="button" class="btn ">Select Your Location</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li ng-repeat="perlocation in locations"><a ng-click='loadCalendar(perlocation)'>{{perlocation.name}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <tabset justified="true">
          <tab heading="Sunday"></tab>
          <tab heading="Monday">Monday</tab>
          <tab heading="Tuesday">Tuesday</tab>
          <tab heading="Wednesday">Wednesday</tab>
          <tab heading="Thursday">Thursday</tab>
          <tab heading="Friday">Friday</tab>
          <tab heading="Saturday">Saturday</tab>
        </tabset>
   </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

my partial file sundayPartial.html

```
<div>
  <h3>Sunday Here</h3>
</div>
```

So basically when i click on Sunday tab, it should load the `sundayPartial.html` under the tab Sunday

My app.js

```
angular
  .module('letsSchedulecommyApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.calendar',
    'ngSanitize'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/cleaning_services/homepage.html',
        controller: 'CleaningServicesCtrl'
      })
});
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<div ng-include src="'sundayPartial.html'"></div>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need some basic routing. You can use the built-in angular routing or something more advanced, like [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest write a single route for all days

**Code**

```
$scope.days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sundays"];
```

**Markup**

```
<tabset justified="true">
   <tab ng-repeat="day in days" heading="{{day}}">{{day}}</tab>
</tabset>
<div ng-view></div>
```

**Route**

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/cleaning_services/homepage.html',
      controller: 'CleaningServicesCtrl'
    })
    .when('/:day', {
      templateUrl: 'views/cleaning_services/day.html',
      controller: 'dayCtrl'
    })
});
```

Comment: i dont have any day controller neither do i plan to setup one so is there any way to do it without setting up a new controller?